# VC carousel in wordpress - overwriting the code/getting to the object in jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, debugging

I have a problem with the gap after the carousel, please see what I mean:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJ2-fMjRROY&feature=youtu.be&t=274

And my question is how to get to the jquery object from custom js code and modify it? How can I debug it?

I know how to make it infinite, I just don't know, how to overwrite the js code.

I want to do something like that, but within an object

```
$('vc_carousel-slideline .vc_item.vc_active:nth-last-of-type(5)').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('vc_active');
    $('vc_carousel-slideline .vc_item:first-of-type').addClass('vc_active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

create/edit custom.js file of your theme

```
(function ($) { 
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.vc_carousel-slideline-inner .vc_item:nth-last-of-type(5)').addClass("last-logo"); 
    $('.vc_carousel-slideline .vc_item.vc_active.last-logo').each(function() { 
      $(this).removeClass('vc_active'); 
      $('.vc_carousel-slideline .vc_item:first-of-type').addClass('vc_active'); 
      $('.vc_carousel-slideline .vc_item:nth-last-of-type(4)').removeClass('vc_active'); 
    }); 
  }); 
  setInterval(carouselfix, 500); 

  function carouselfix() { 
    $('.vc_carousel-slideline .vc_item.last-logo').removeClass('vc_active'); 
  } 
})(jQuery, this);
```

Not the perfect solution, but it works